# Make empty div of one line height

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a rule that will make the following HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%"></div>
```

of one line height using just CSS, or do I need to put `&nbsp;` as the content?

Comment: The real question is "Why do you want to do this?". I suspect that there a is a better way to doing whatever it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Paulie_D I need to for jQuery terminal if you echo emtpy string you got empty div that it's not visible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Set [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) (or [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)) to the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)'s [used value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#used-value).

  The initial value of `line-height` is `normal`, whose used value is implementation-dependent, but the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) suggests a number between `1.0` and `1.2`

  In my case (FF27 for winXP with `font-family: "times new roman"`) that value is `1.25`, so you could use `height: 1.25em`. However, that value might be different with other fonts or implementations.

  Then, it's better to manually set `line-height` to some value, like `line-height: 1.25em`.

  ```css
  div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.25;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div></div>
  ```

  Note that if you want to set those styles to the elements only when it has no content, you can use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class:

  ```css
  div:empty {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.25;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div></div>
  ```

  Inserting some content to the element.

  For example, you can add a normal space and set [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `pre-wrap` (or `pre`) to prevent the space from collapsing:

  ```css
  div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div> </div>
  ```

  Alternatively, you can use a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (`&#8203;`)

  ```css
  div { border: 1px solid red; }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>​</div><!-- There is a zero-width space inside -->
  ```

  As you say, `&nbsp;` would also work. However, it is a non-breaking space, so its purpose is preventing automatic line breaks. Then, using it would be semantically incorrect IMO.

  And as @BoltClock [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348054/1529630), those whitespaces could be inserted with CSS pseudo-elements, but note that might not work on very old browsers.

Comment: min-height is the best solution for me because I need to have divs that are heigher then one line. so I put `min-height:14px` the same as my line-height.

Comment: The quantity `1.25em` does not equal the height of a line, except by accident.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You're right, I should have noted that it works using `font-family: "times new roman"`, which is the default font on FF27 for WinXP. Other fonts could have other aspect ratios.

Comment: This has nothing to do with aspect ratios. And the default line height depends on the font and on the browser. It is pointless to assume that that a specific font will be used and it has a specific default line height, when you can simply set line height.

Comment: Uhm, 2 years later I don't like how I wrote this answer. I have improved it a bit, but even after the edit I prefer BoltCock's one.

Answer (score 30):

Just another solution:

```
.your-selector:empty::after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is both clever and elegant -- it lets the line follow the style without having to specify heights.  In my implementation, I used `&nbsp;` instead of a period.

Comment: Use `content: '\200B'` for a zero width space.

Comment: This is a good solution, but be aware it only works when there is no whitspace present! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/CSS/_colon_empty

Answer (score 21):

That depends on your definition of a single-line height, since there isn't a CSS unit that corresponds to the computed line height of an element.

If you know the exact `line-height` value for this element, then you can just explicitly set `height` to the same value. But, given your question, this is likely not the case.

There is a unit that corresponds to font size, `em`, which you can use if the height of one line is equal to the computed font size:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 1em"></div>
```

Otherwise you will have to put in some sort of filler content. You can either throw in an `&nbsp;` and be done with it:

```
<div style="width: 100%">&nbsp;</div>
```

Or go a little overkill by writing a CSS rule with a pseudo-element, but you must be able to target this element somehow:

```
div::before { content: '\00a0'; }
```

If the element may or may not have content but you want it to have a minimum height,

- use `min-height` where you would have used `height` instead, or
- select `div:empty::before` instead if you choose to use a pseudo-element so the filler doesn't get inserted if there is content.

Comment: If line height is set in the document, as it normally should be, then you can make the height setting match that. E.g., with `* { line-height: 1.3 }`, you can set `div { min-height: 1.3em }`.

Comment: Using `em` does non seem to be working, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M5EPg/ It seems to be now that the best way to use `&nbsp`

Comment: `\00a0` is a non-breaking space, right? Why couldn't you use a zero-width space, like in @Oriol's answer? I think this would be `\200b`, correct?

Comment: @trysis: You could, in fact. I would recommend writing the escape sequence in CSS `\200b` or the character reference in HTML `&#8203;` just for the sake of clarity so someone else reading your code doesn't mistake `<div>​</div>` for an empty div. Also, a no-break space is much more widely recognized as used with spacer elements than a zero-width space.

Answer (score 12):

The solution with `visibility: hidden;` is clever. It is simpler to set the content to Unicode character `feff`, which is the byte order mark. This has no width but has height; it behaves the same on every browser all the way back to IE6.

```
.your-selector:empty::before {
    content: '\feff';
}
```

I have found that WebKit (at least on Mac OS) applies slightly different (1px) line height to bold text than normal text for some fonts. To enforce uniformity (in this case, we would need to apply even to non-empty selectors):

```
.your-selector::before {
    content: '\feff';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Many years later, there are new css units available for the matter: `lh` and `rlh`.

```
div {
    min-height: 1lh;
}
```

[But the support is lacking (caniuse#lh)](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_lh). Currently it's supported by Chrome, Edge, and Opera. Not supported by Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: As of November 2023, this is now supported by all major browsers

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was with jQuery Terminal that needed to have empty line same size of normal lines. Other solution was problematic because when using fixed line-height there was gaps between lines also there was [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1651900) that I've reported about layout with font-size + line-height.

By best solution so far is this:

```
div::before {
    content: '\0200B';
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

and no line-height/min-height in the code and it works perfectly. Also when not using line-height it have good looking style selection without gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hack.

```html
<div style="width: 100%">&ZeroWidthSpace;</div>
```

Comment: I don't want this character to end up in user output when copying and pasting.

Answer (score -3):

What height do you want to keep? Will that be in relation with your font-size? That can be in em, pt, px or %.

This is just an example where 1.5em is arbitrary value:

`<div style="width: 100%; height: 5px" ></div>`

If you don't have anything to write in this div, use some height value.

Comment: "some height value" **What** height value exactly? That's what he's asking. 5px seems incredibly arbitrary.

Comment: I believe he wants to make it equal to the line-height of the text

Comment: Then I think he should at least add 1 px to the font-size he is going to use for the text inside this div. I have given him an idea, because adding &nbsp; is a bad idea.