# What character should I use to maintain height of an empty (zero width) string?

Tags: html

I have a string that can potentially be empty, and in that case, I want to substitute it with a special character to maintain the ordinary text height while having zero width. In TeX, this would be called `\strut`. What is the counterpart for that in HTML? I came up with two candidates: `&#x2060;` and `&#xfeff;`. Should I use one of these?

Comment: You may be able to use CSS to enforce this minimum line-height depending on your layout instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347988/how-to-make-empty-div-one-line-height-using-css

Comment: @BoltClock That solution seems to be dependent on the choice of the font and the browser, so I do not think it is robust.

Comment: The accepted solution? Yeah, I don't know why that solution was accepted. Have you seen my answer to that question?

Comment: @BoltClock I saw your answer, and that eventually uses the equivalent of `&nbsp;` on `:before` pseudo selector.

Comment: You can always replace the `&nbsp;` with a zero-width alternative. Or just go with Jukka's answer as you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On modern browsers, any zero-width character will do the job, provided that the browser either knows that the character is zero-width or uses a font that contains an empty glyph for it. But some characters may have effects, depending on the context and on software used to process the HTML file.

U+2060 WORD JOINER has the effect of preventing line break.

U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE has the same effect. It is formally deprecated for any use except as Byte Order Mark, but in reality it works more often than WORD JOINER (though there are exceptions).

U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE has the effect of *allowing* a line break even when it would otherwise not be permitted; it’s like SPACE, but with zero width.

Usually the worst-case scenario for characters like this is an old version of IE. Checking in IE 6 shows that U+FEFF and U+200B are OK, but U+2060 shows as a small rectangle (i.e., the browser tries to render the character but finds no glyph for it).

So I’d use `&#xfeff;` or `&#x200b;` depending on whether I’d like to prevent or allow line break at that point. If it does not matter, `&#x200b;` is more logical to use.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest `&#xfeff;` or if zero width is not essential `&nbsp;` or if it is essential you could try the Unicode character `&#8288;` which is a zero width non-breaking space.